# Is there a way to update all "GETDATE" functions in SQL Server in a prewritten script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We had a data failure and need to rerun several days worth of reports that typically run as stored procedures. These scripts are 100s of lines long and rely heavily on `GETDATE()` functionality to pull the data.

For all of these reports we need to back track -3, -2 and -1 and rerun the reports.

Aside from going through and updating each instance of `GETDATE()`, is there a way to do a mass update in SQL Server?

Trying to avoid going line by line.

Comment: Are you indicating that you have a main script that, in turn, runs the stored procedures? Are you wanting to change each stored procedure? You could script them out, run search and replace on all, the save and run them.

Comment: There is no simple solution (apert from changing the time on the server, which could be an ever bigger disaster). This is one of the reasons why I tend to end up parametrising such statements and setting the parameters to a value based on a function like `GETDATE()`. Not a solution for the immediate issue, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's not really an answer, but `CTRL-H` in SSMS will open the find and replace functionality.

Comment: No. There's probably some `where dt > getdate() - 1` kind of business somewhere.

Comment: Pretty sure SSMS has Find and Replace feature.

Comment: My first idea was to overload it, but that is not possible, see: [Is it Possible to Overload SQL Server Functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211449/is-it-possible-to-overload-sql-server-functions)

Comment: The other advantage of using a helper function instead of `GETDATE()` directly is that this makes your TSQL more testable. e.g. you can use `tSQLt.FakeFunction` in your tSQLt tests to mock whatever datetime you want